# Heroku deployment assistance. .env file not being read but is in file structure?

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, environment

I am trying to deploy on heroku but I keep getting this .env error, but it is present in my project. Could someone give some direction as to what I can do to resolve this or any possible mistakes I made?

```
tmp/build_057816491291ab18684f7791472a55f4/config/env.js:7
throw Error(’.env not found, please copy sample.env to .env.’);
^
Error: .env not found, please copy sample.env to .env.
at Object. (/tmp/build_057816491291ab18684f7791472a55f4/config/env.js:7:11)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object. (/tmp/build_057816491291ab18684f7791472a55f4/tools/scripts/build/ensure-env.js:5:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
at Object.Module._extensions…js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @freecodecamp/freecodecamp@0.0.1 ensure-env: cross-env DEBUG=fcc:* node ./tools/scripts/build/ensure-env.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @freecodecamp/freecodecamp@0.0.1 ensure-env script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.kGGVT/_logs/2020-07-09T14_23_29_322Z-debug.log
ERROR: “ensure-env” exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @freecodecamp/freecodecamp@0.0.1 build: npm-run-all ensure-env -p build:*
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @freecodecamp/freecodecamp@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.kGGVT/_logs/2020-07-09T14_23_29_344Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

you will not be able to use a .env file on heroku.You need to either use the heroku cli to set this

```
heroku config:set DBHOST=database_host_here
heroku config:set DBPASS=database_pass_here
```

or you can use the [heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) settings tab to edit config vars

[image: Config vars on dashboard]

reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars